# PHPMailer Use of dkim signature

Tags: php, email, encryption, hash, dkim

I am currently using PHPmailer to send emails from my website.

Everything works fine, and I am able to send emails with SPF signature as I already configured DNS.

Now I have a problem with the dkim signature, I already tried without success to add the signature manually with in the $header of the message with the use of the send() function in PHP.

Now I am using the phpmailer method `mail->send()` and it is still not working. My signature is recognized by dkimcore.

This mail tester http://www.appmaildev.com/fr/dkim tells me that my DKIM test failed because my body hash is wrong and they tell me how the `bh=` parameter should look like.

Here is my question: How did they obtain this parameter?

For example if I send as a body "Hello" is there a library that does the sha256, RSA and base64 encryption that I can see the result expected?

How to make sure that my body hash is correctly generated?

Here is the code to send the email:

```
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message_html;
$mail->AltBody = $message_txt;

$mail->DKIM_domain = 'mydomain.com';
$mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;
$mail->DKIM_private_string = "dkim/private.key";
$mail->DKIM_selector = 'default';
```